# How to set margins correctly in joomla custom html

Tags: css, joomla

Kindly assist with some CSS code. I need to have the two content holders ie.Sentrim 680 Hotel and Sentrim Boulevard in http://kaskazibeachhotel.co.ke/live/ frontpage have 0 margins both on the left side and on the right side so that the boxes align well with the website slide which is a 980px width.

I would also need to maintain the space in between the two boxes.
I know this question might be wrongly posted because its a debug but I think this is the only place i can get good help as of now. Please assist.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS to your site:

```
/* Remove padding for these elements */
#midblock, .insidem, .news_item_a, .item, .newsitem_text { padding: 0; } 

 /* Add space between boxes. Change values as needed */
#midblock .item.column-2 { padding-left: 5px; }
#midblock .item.column-1 { padding-right: 5px; }
```

In addition, your main image is slightly displaced, adding this should fix it:

```
.yjsquare.modid94 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this code worked perfectly. I really appreciate and thats exactly what I wanted to achieve. If I wanted to put a box shadow to the main image using this code box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999; on which style would I put the code. Great help

Comment: @DanielKamau - Your question has already been answered. If you have a different question, please ask a new one and also start trying to use your browser inspector.

Comment: @Lodder Thanks for your comments but I am not able to ask another question as of now until 4 days. Thats why I just added up on the comment for someone to assist.

Comment: `#slider-container94 img {box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;}` You can't call yourself a web developer without knowing how to inspect an element in your browser... Try hitting `F12` or right-click any element and select "inspect element". Or simply Google it.